# Shiny is undefined in iframe

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am currently trying to develop a  minimal working CustomMessageHandling dashbord in R. What I am doing is simply sending a message from my R client side to my Javascript file, which is then run in an html file. The error is as follows:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Shiny is not defined ReferenceError: Shiny is not defined
```

In my JavaScript file, which is called in my .html file, I simply add it at the bottom of the file, which looks like:

```
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
  console.log("Hello, I am executing!");
  const clientID = "e800d12fc12c4d60960778b2bc4370af";
  var urlToBase64PDF;

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('handler1', function()
    {
      doUpdate();
    }
    );

  function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64)
    {
    var bin = window.atob(base64);
    var len = bin.length;
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      uInt8Array[i] = bin.charCodeAt(i);

    }
      return uInt8Array.buffer;
    }


  function doUpdate(message1)
    {
    urlToBase64PDF = message1;
    }


  document.write(urlToBase64PDF);
  console.log(urlToBase64PDF);

  document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function()
  {
    var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: clientID, divId: "adobe-dc-view"});
    document.write(urlToBase64PDF);
    console.log(urlToBase64PDF);
    adobeDCView.previewFile({content:{ promise: Promise.resolve(base64ToArrayBuffer(urlToBase64PDF))}, metaData:{fileName: "check.pdf"}},
    {});
  });



});
```

In my .html file, I call it in the following fashion:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1"/>
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</head>
```

The rest of the functionality is built in Shiny in R, which are extremely simple UI and Server parts:

```
app_ui <- function() {
  shiny::addResourcePath(
    'www', system.file('app/www', package = 'test')
  )

  tags$iframe(src="www/index.html", height = 600, width = 600)
```

and lastly the server part:

```
app_server <- function(input, output, session){
  shinyjs::useShinyjs()
    message1 = "test"
    session$sendCustomMessage("handler1", message1)
  }
```

I have literally tried everything, searched everywhere, and even the documentation on CustomMessageHandling sends messages in the above fashion. Yet I still get the Shiny undefined Error in my console.

Edit: Exact error:

No output to console at all.

Comment: Try **$(document).ready(......**.

Comment: Update: Wrapping the entire javascript code in $(document).ready() does not solve the problem, sadly. I updated the snippet accordingly.

Comment: Ok. Then I would try **$(document).on("shiny:connected", ......**.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you for the suggestion. It actually did get rid of the error in my console. Now, my console registers no errors. If I, however, try to do a simple "console.log("I am executing");" within my JavaScript file, then nothing is output to the console. This suggests that it may not even connect!

Edit: I updated my JS code accordingly.

Comment: Hmm strange. I never use HTML files. You can also try the event **shiny:sessioninitialized**.

Comment: Yeah -- same error. I see the body load upon running the application, yet nothing happens. No errors still. I doubt that the HTML is the problem, but I have never tried using HTML, JS + R in a singular application. The only thing I wanted to accomplish was to link a server variable  to the JavaScript variable UrlToBase64PDF and then execute the HTML file. I still suspect that the session is not connecting, also with ```sessioninitialized```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables from the parent frame in embedded `iframe`. This is due to security reasons. So `Shiny` is never defined in `iframe` and any `shiny` event cannot be listened in `iframe`.

what you see is following:

```js
console.log("script starts")
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
  console.log("oh yeah")
  // do some other things
});
console.log("script ends")
```

```js
// index.js:1 script starts
// index.js:6 script ends
```

You can see the middle part is never run, because there is no `shiny:connected` event at all. When you are listening to unknown events, sadly it doesn't report any error messages.

Change to this makes it clearer:

```js
console.log("script starts")
$(function(){
    console.log(Shiny)
})
console.log("script ends")
```

```js
index.js:1 script starts
index.js:5 script ends
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Shiny is not defined ReferenceError: Shiny is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3168/www/index.js:3:17)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Shiny is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:3:17)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2:30307)
```

Even we waited for the document to be ready, you can see there is still no `Shiny`.

Then you will ask so where does the `jquery` comes from. Well, you re-imported in your `index.html`:  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. That's why you can use `jquery` but not `Shiny`.

##### Solution

A simple solution is to use serverside rendering, so it makes sure the iframe is set up after Shiny is initialized.

```r
library(shiny)

addResourcePath('www', "./")
ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("iframe")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$iframe <- renderUI({
        tags$iframe(src="www/index.html", height = 600, width = 600)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This only solves part of your problem. I see you have a custom handler that sends out an update command based on some other things that are controlled by Shiny. In this case, there is no easy solution, you need [cross-origin communication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

In the next example, I use a button to simulate your update event and it is controlled by shiny `observeEvent`. Once clicked, it sends the `sendCustomMessage`. On UI, we add some script to listen to this message and then, dispatch the event to `iframe` by `postMessage`.

```r
library(shiny)

addResourcePath('www', "./")
ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("iframe"),
    actionButton("update", "update"),
    tags$script(HTML(
    "
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('handler1', function(data){
        if(data.msg !== 'update') return ;
        $('#myiframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(data.msg, '*');
    });
    "
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$iframe <- renderUI({
        tags$iframe(id = "myiframe", src="www/index.html", height = 600, width = 600)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$update, {
        session$sendCustomMessage("handler1", list(msg = "update"))
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In iframe `index.js` we use `window.onmessage` listener to catch our message

```js
console.log("script starts")
$(function(){
    window.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
        if (e.data === 'update') $('body').append('<h1>Oh yeah !</h1>');
    });
})
console.log("script ends")
```

This example appends a `h1` every time you click `update` from the parent site to the iframe.

[image]